# How does this object auto increment?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I can see why it works, but how it works, I'm not so sure. I'm assuming it has something to do with this.count = this.count + 1 equaling ++, but why doesn't it just increment by 1 and not by 5?

```js
class Multiplier {
  constructor() {
    this.count = 1
  }
  increment() {
    this.count = this.count + 1;
  }
  apply(x) {
    return this.count * x;
  }
}

let multiplier = new Multiplier();
console.log(multiplier.apply(5)); //multiplier.apply(5) = 5
multiplier.increment(); //miltiplier.increment(++) = 10
multiplier.increment(); //multiplier.increment(++) = 15
console.log(multiplier.apply(5)); // 15*
```

Comment: It does increment by 1, not by 5.

Comment: In your case, doing two `multiplier.increment()` makes `this.count` equal to 3. Then, `3 * 5 = 15`.

Comment: That makes loads of sence! Feeling silly..

Answer (score 2):

```
apply(x) {
    return this.count * x;
}
```

This does not change your `count` value. It just returns a value which is the multiplication of `count` and 5.

You may consider rewriting that as follows:

```
apply(x) {
    this.count = this.count * x;
    return this.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just correct apply method with :

```
apply(x) {
    return this.count *= x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working as below:

```
let multiplier = new Multiplier();
console.log(multiplier.apply(5)); //multiplier.apply(5) = 5
multiplier.increment(); // this.count = 1 + 1 =2;
multiplier.increment(); // this.count = 2 + 1 =3
console.log(multiplier.apply(5)); // 3 * 5 =15
```

To correct it

```
 return this.count *= x;
```